# Data handling /conversion

Tags: d3.js

help needed to convert data from var data to var csv format below 
to work with this example  http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/T3qHk/1/ or modify the code to work with var data

```
var csv = [
["State","Gp1","Gp2","Gp3","Gp4","Gp5","Gp6","Gp7"],
["CA",2704659,4499890,2159981,3853788,10604510,8819342,4114496],
["TX",2027307,,1420518,2454721,7017731,,2472223],
["NY",1208495,2141490,1058031,1999120,,5120254,2607672],
["FL",1140516,,,,,4746856,3187797],
["IL",894368,,725973,1311479,,3239173,1575308],
["PA",737462,1345341,679201,1203944,,,1910571]
].map(function(d){return d.join(',')}).join('\n');



var data = [

{ "state": "CA", "Gp1": 2704659, "Gp2": 2704659, "Gp3": 2704659, "Gp4": 3853788 },
{ "state": "TX", "Gp1": 2027307, "Gp2": 4499890, "Gp3": 2159981, "Gp4": 3853788 },
{ "state": "NY", "Gp1": 1208495, "Gp2": 1208495, "Gp3": 1420518, "Gp4": 2454721 },
{ "state": "FL", "Gp1": 1140516, "Gp2": 2141490, "Gp3": 1058031, "Gp4": 1999120 },
{ "state": "IL", "Gp1": 894368, "Gp2": 894368, "Gp3": 1058031, "Gp4": 1311479 },
{ "state": "PA", "Gp1": 737462, "Gp2": 1345341, "Gp3": 1058031, "Gp4": 1203944 },

];
```

Thank you

Comment: The fiddle code you're linking to already successfully converts your artificially constructed csv string to a data object of the second format.  What else do you need help with?  (P.S.  the consecutive commas are probably not doing what you want, and will create errors in some browsers; you'd need an empty string or a zero as a placeholder to make each array the same length.)

Comment: Thanks, how do I modify the code to work with var data?  I tried substitution but it failed!

Comment: Two changes:  replace the csv functions that create `data` with your `data`, and replace every reference to `"State"` with `"state"`.  Javascript is case-sensitive!  http://jsfiddle.net/T3qHk/3/

Comment: Great thanks.  I was looking too closely at the code and missed the obvious case change!